# Is there a word for when you want something bad to happen and then it happens?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for when you want something bad to happen (usually to someone you dislike) and when it happens you get this feeling?  It's like fulfilment but specifically for a bad thing.

Thank you Old Brixtonian!! That is an awesome word, and it fits perfectly.

Comment: Hi Spencer. Schadenfreude is the pleasure derived by someone from another person's misfortune.

Comment: Note that schadenfreude doesn't necessarily carry any connotation of previously having wished for that particular bad thing to happen to the person.